# Programs slows down when code the is not run is added

Tags: java, performance, frame-rate, bounding-box, voxel

I'm working on a 3D voxel game. In this game I have a bounding box to detect which voxels the player is looking at. Every tick the player is moving.

I have to read just the bounding boxes position. I do this by the following: `this.bb.x0/x1/y0/y1/z0/z1 += xa/ya/za`.

However when I add this code I lose a lot of frames, 150 fps to 15. game slows down even if the code isn't running in the application. What could I do to speed up the application?

Here is my code:

```
public void move(float xa, float ya, float za){
    onGround = false;
    double new_x = this.x + xa;
    double new_y = this.y + ya;
    double new_z = this.z + za;
    if(level.isSolidTile((int)new_x, (int)this.y, (int)this.z)||level.isSolidTile((int)new_x, (int)this.y-1, (int)this.z)||level.isSolidTile((int)new_x, (int)this.y-2, (int)this.z)) {
        new_x = this.x;
        xa = 0;
    } else if(!(xa==0)) {
        //this.bb.move(xa, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.bb.x0 += xa;
        this.bb.x1 += xa;
        System.out.println("no");
    }
    if(level.isSolidTile((int)this.x, (int)new_y-2, (int)this.z)&&new_y<this.y) {
        new_y = this.y;
        ya = 0;
        onGround=true;
    }
    if(level.isSolidTile((int)this.x, (int)new_y, (int)this.z)&&new_y>this.y) {
        new_y = this.y;
        ya = 0;
    } else if(!(ya==0)){
        this.bb.y0 += ya;
        this.bb.y1 += ya;
        System.out.println("no");
    }
    if(level.isSolidTile((int)this.x, (int)this.y, (int)new_z)||level.isSolidTile((int)this.x, (int)this.y-1, (int)new_z)||level.isSolidTile((int)this.x, (int)this.y-2, (int)new_z)) {
      new_z = this.z;
      za = 0;
    } else if(!(xa==0)){
      //this.bb.move(0.0f, 0.0f, za);
      this.bb.z0 += za;
      this.bb.z1 += za;
      System.out.println("no");
    }
    this.setPos((float) new_x,(float) new_y, (float) new_z);
    if(!((xa+ya+za)==0)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's not rather the `System.out.println("no")`...

Comment: As i said i never saw any "no" in the console.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the code that isn't executed that slows you program down: it's the code that IS executed.

Comment: Maybe it's the numerous calls to `isSolidTile` in the `if` conditions? Which lines exactly cause the difference in execution time? Just the assignments, or did you add/uncomment the entire `move` function?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post its the this.bb lines that decrease the fps

Comment: Evidently `isSolidTile` is something to time. Also `setPos`.

Comment: Is solid tile and setPos are not that time consuming. I have checked and its the this.bb lines that are responsible. I have removed them and the fps went up to 150

Comment: If `this.bb` influence the speed, maybe `setPos` uses them? As `bb`probably stands for bounding box and is some simple Rectangle, that seems the only explanation.

Comment: But those are just assignments. They should not be that time consuming, at least not on their own. Maybe another part of your code monitors whether the `bb` has changed since the last iteration and then executes some other time consuming code, slowing down the execution?

Comment: perhaps ill take a look